# Finding a value of range less than or greater than from container class

Tags: c++, stl

Currently, I have a `std::map <DWORD, DWORD>` table and I'm looking for a key value matching a specific range.

For example:

Find a key value from map whose value should be either less than < 50 or greater than > 50 from the searched key value.

If the searched key value was 20 then I would want a key value of range from map i.e

```
-70.............20............+70
```

is there a better way to find a key value other than using two loop (first for less than, second for greater than) or an appropriate way to store table data for such operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map::lower_bound` and `map::upper_bound` for this, if you know the midrange value upfront.

```
map<int, MyClass>::const_iterator lower = 
    myMap.lower_bound(-30);   // or -70 if you prefer
map<int, MyClass>::const_iterator upper = myMap.lower_bound(70);
```

Both iterators need to be checked for `myMap.end()` before you dereference.

This snippet relies on your ordering being the usual ascending order - custom ordering could reverse this so that -ve numbers appears after +ve.  There is no better way to do this - by construction of the `map` as a binary tree, this will be efficient.

See also online samples for [lower_bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6539ey2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [upper_bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68x89d6f.aspx).

Note that `DWORD` is unsigned, so use of negative numbers in your map may give you a warning error, and -70 being unexpectedly > 70.

Comment: as far as i understand op he wants keys by searching the values from specific range and `map::*_bound` works for keys not values

Comment: @erjot - wording is ambiguous but the first sentence mentions "key value matching a specific range".

Comment: and second one `Find a key from map which value should be` ;) imho op should reconsider changing the data structure he uses

Comment: @erjot I meant the value of searched key.