# How to find all elements in a range in STL map(set)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a map in stl and a range [lo, hi].

What is the best way to find all elements in map which fit in this range?

UDT:

The question about upper_bound and low_bound is:

For example I have a set or map with {1, 2, 7, 8} and my range is [3,6]. lower_bound will points to 7 and upper_bound to 2. Assume I don't want to erase smith, but just write out all elements in a range. How can I do it? And what complexity will be for erasing in this case?

Comment: @Nikita What tree are you saying about?

Comment: Sorry, not tree, but map

Comment: maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164326/finding-a-value-of-range-less-than-or-greater-than-from-container-class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using std::map, it's already sorted, your can use lower_bound/upper_bound an example from cplusplus.com:

```
// map::lower_bound/upper_bound
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator itlow,itup;

  mymap['a']=20;
  mymap['b']=40;
  mymap['c']=60;
  mymap['d']=80;
  mymap['e']=100;

  itlow=mymap.lower_bound ('b');  // itlow points to b
  itup=mymap.upper_bound ('d');   // itup points to e (not d!)

  mymap.erase(itlow,itup);        // erases [itlow,itup)

  // print content:
  for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I check there are some elements between it low and itUp. Basically the question is about the complexity of my map.erase(.., ..) in a case there are no elements between them

Comment: For example I have a set or map with {1, 2, 7, 8} and my range is [3,6]. lower_bound will points to 7 and upper_bound to 2. Assume I don't want to erase smith, but just write out all elements in a range. How can I do it?

Comment: to check if there are elements between the range, you need to check itlow and itup are not map::end and not equal. Not sure I understand your second comment, erase is just an example, you can do whatever you want with itlow and itup, think of it as begin and end iterator of a container

Comment: I finally got it! upper_bound iterator will points to e ( not d! ) to manage a case I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::map<int, char> m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) m.insert( { i, char( 'A' + i ) } );

    std::pair<int, int> range( 3, 7 );

    auto low = m.lower_bound( range.first );
    auto upper = m.upper_bound( range.second );

    if ( low != upper )
    {
        for ( auto it = low; it != upper; ++it )
        {
            std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
3 D
4 E
5 F
6 G
7 H
```

Here is a program written specially for your example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, char> m = { { 1, 'B' }, { 2, 'C' },  { 7, 'H' }, { 8, 'I' } };

    std::pair<int, int> range( 3, 6 );

    auto low = m.lower_bound( range.first );
    auto upper = m.upper_bound( range.second );

    if ( low != upper )
    {
        for ( auto it = low; it != upper; ++it )
        {
            std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The range is empty" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The range is empty
```

Comment: In my update the problem occurs when there is no elements in a range. So upperIt is less then loIt. In that case your code fails. How to fix it? And will be the complexity of this operation in that particular case?

Comment: In my example low is still not equal upper, but the iterating is still impossible.

Comment: @Nikita  I tried your example and the code is compiles an runs successfully. Simply the range will be empty and nothing will be outputed.